# Getting a weird negative number in my output when using an array I modified in one function, in another function

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I am writing a program that takes a user-inputted list of up to 25 integers, then prints the sorted list using bubble sorting, the sorted list in descending order, and some other info about the list like the median, minimum and maximum, and mode.

I have tested all of my functions within the program individually on an array I created using initializer lists (not from user input/cin) and they work fine, but when I run the program something is off. For example, when I input 1,2,3,4, the function that prints the sorted list in descending order prints 3,2,1, -858993460. It always leaves out the greatest integer and adds on -858993460 at the end no matter what values I put into the input array. Here's the relevant part of my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void input(int ulist[26], int& n);
void Bubblesort(int ulist[26], int slist[26], int n);
void print(int list[26], int n);
int n;
void reversesort(int slist[26], int n);


void main()
{
    int ulist[26], slist[26];
    input(ulist, n); 
    cout << "Unsorted";
    print(ulist, n);
    cout << "Sorted";
    Bubblesort(ulist, slist, n);
    print(slist, n);
    reversesort(slist, n);   
    cin >> n;
}

void input(int ulist[26], int& n)
{
    int i(0), value;
    cout << "enter value : \n";
    cin >> value;

    while (i < 25 && value != -999)
    {
        ulist[i] = value;
        i++;
        if (i < 25)
        {
            cin >> value;
        }
    }
    n = i;
}

void Bubblesort(int ulist[26], int slist[26], int n)
{
    int i, j, temp;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        slist[i] = ulist[i];

    for (j = 25 - 1; j > 0; j--)        //25 is Length of the array 
        for (i = 0; i < j; i++)
            if (slist[i] > slist[i + 1])
            {
                temp = slist[i];
                slist[i] = slist[i + 1];
                slist[i + 1] = temp;
            }

}

void print(int list[26], int n)
{
    int i;
    cout << " list of numbers are : \n"; 
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        cout << list[i] << '\n';
    }
    cout << "\n\n";
}

void reversesort(int slist[26], int n) //checked w online compiler, works
{
    cout << "List of numbers in descending order is: \n";
    for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; --i)
        cout << slist[i] << ", ";
    cout << "\n";
}
```

I'm assuming this is some sort of memory problem and that the source of this has to do with passing slist, which was modified in the bubblesort function, through the functions I wrote. I'm pretty new to C++ (coming from python) so I'm assuming I'm missing something as far as passing arrays to functions is concerned.

EDIT: I guess to sum everything up - how can I take the data inputted in the input function and use that array in another function? And how can I take the array that has been sorted by the bubblesort function and use that array in another function?

Comment: `reversesort` prints `slist[0]`, but no other function ever assigns to an element at index zero.

Comment: Arrays indices in C++ start at 0, not at 1. Probably that why you are accessing invalid values.

Comment: You should use the standard STL containers (`std::array` for example), this would certainly be less of a problem for you than using C-like tables, which is a bad practice in C++.

Comment: Oh, and side note: `foo(int[26])` is equivalent to `foo(int[])` and equivalent to `foo(int*)`. Your array decays to a pointer anyway, so compiler ignores it.

Comment: "*I'm assuming this is some sort of memory problem*" - so you ran it under Valgrind to check, then?  It's worth including the results of your investigation so far.

Comment: Avoid using global variables (n and sum).

Comment: @TobySpeight not sure what valgrind is - I thought that maybe the source of the problem had something to do with slist being modified in one function but used in another function, so I tried putting the bubblesort code itself in the main block instead of the function call but the problem still persisted.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik thanks for pointing that out! Have changed the code a bit to solve that issue but I'm still getting the same problem.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik thanks for pointing that out! Have changed the code a bit to solve that issue but I'm still getting the same problem.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen thanks for pointing that out! Have changed the code a bit to solve that issue but I'm still getting the same problem. And thank you for that note about arrays - so if I declared an array like so: int foo[100] but only planned on it having 5 elements, the remaining 95 would just be ignored completely?

Comment: @Foxy interesting, would you mind elaborating more on why that is? My professor actually gave us the functions input, print and bubblesort (we are supposed to use them in our program) so I figured that was the way to do it.  What exactly are "C-like tables" and how would doing what you suggested potentially fix the problem I'm running in to?

Comment: @stark thanks for the reply, why is that? I kind of need them as I have about five more functions that require n (I actually don't need some, will delete that) so I figured it makes sense to have that be a global variable rather than write the code to find n in every function. Is there a better alternative that doesn't rely on global variables?

Comment: If a function needs information, pass it as an argument. `void main` is wrong: `main` must return `int`. `using namespace std;` is a bad idea. Don't use `>>` for user input. When you use `>>`, always check the return value to make sure it succeeded.

Comment: @ggaugler: C-like arrays are native to the language, static and with a predefined size. They are "dangerous" to use because they are more at risk of poor management, especially with pointers and overflow/underflow. Loops must also be used to browse and modify them, which can also be "dangerous" for the reasons mentioned above. A container in the standard library (STL) is more suiarray because it completely handles these exceptions/errors, and offers methods and fields that make it easier to handle arrays.

Comment: @melpomene would you mind elaborating why that is the case? I am new to C++ so want to make sure I understand the why of what I'm doing wrong. Changing void main to int main didn't solve my issue, and I'm fairly certain >> has succeeded - the main block and input, print and bubble sort programs were written by my professor (we are supposed to use them in our programs), and bubblesort works fine without returning that weird negative number at the end.

Answer (score 0):

The first instance of undefined behavior in your code is

```
    if (slist[i] > slist[i + 1])
```

in `Bubblesort`.

Due to

```
for (j = 25 - 1; j > 0; j--)
    for (i = 0; i < j; i++)
```

the maximum index accessed by this loop is `slist[24]` (24 from `i + 1` where `i < j` and `j = 25 - 1 = 24`, so `i = 23`).

Your input is only 4 numbers, so only `slist[0]` through `slist[3]` are initialized. The remaining elements (`slist[4]` through `slist[25]`) are uninitialized. Reading from an uninitialized variable has undefined behavior.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I changed the for loop to say for (j=n) and the problem is still there though. Tried j=25 and j=26 as well and am still getting that weird error.